# windows phone 8.1 launch files and return

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to launch a number of files using `var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);` 
the files are launched but how can i return to my app? Or better is there any way to kill/close the files that are launched after a period of time?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do that with the platform. As per my understanding, the system takes over as soon as you call the `LaunchFileAsync()` and your app loses control over. After that user can return to your app (by pressing back, relaunching using a tile, etc.) or system can return to your app if user is done with the file. See here for the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've read all these and i was wondering if there is some "hack" or some other way to launch files in windows phone 8.1.

Comment: Is there any way to launch the files in background?

Comment: @user3640195 Unfortunately, no. And if you think about it, it all makes sense. For all we know, some developer could launch those files in background and carry out some unintended/malicious activity. So, even if you did manage to find a loophole to achieve what you want, the app would get rejected in certification step. As a curiosity: what kind of workflow requires this? Maybe, you could rethink that.

Comment: I am writing a file fuzzer for my masters' thesis...so i need to launch multiple files automatically. I'll try to launch them in background..it might work.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `LaunchFileAsync`, you are asking the system to find and launch an app that can render the file that you're providing. By design, the launch is intended to be "fire and forget" and the system maintains no relationship between the source and target apps. To illustrate this, you can press and hold the back button to bring up the task switcher and see that the two apps are distinct entries in the backstack - forcibly closing the source app has no impact on the target.